# How to create an excel file with an autofilter in the first row with xlwt?

Tags: python, excel, xlwt, pyexcelerator

I am using Python 2.6 + xlwt module to generate excel files.

Is it possible to include an autofilter in the first row with xlwt or pyExcelerator or anything else besides COM?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK xlwt doesn't allow you to add a filter.

However you can add a filter using [Mark Hammond's Python Win32 Extensions](http://starship.python.net/crew/mhammond/win32/Downloads.html). Download for 2.6 [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/).
Something like this should work (tested in Python 2.5.4):

```
from win32com.client import DispatchEx
xl = DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
xl.Workbooks.Open("c:/excel_file.xls")
xl.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Columns(1).AutoFilter(1)
xl.ActiveWorkbook.Close(SaveChanges=1)
xl.Quit()
del xl # ensure excel.exe process ends
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but my server is running on Linux so I am unable to use the COM. :-(

Comment: @jbochi:  No problem.  You may want to update the question with this additional piece of information.

Comment: this is not working for me. please help me out . i am getting this error      xl = DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 113, in DispatchEx
    dispatch = pythoncom.CoCreateInstanceEx(clsid, None, clsctx, serverInfo, (pythoncom.IID_IDispatch,))[0]
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221005, 'Invalid class string', None, None)

Answer (score 2):

I found [this message](http://groups.google.com.au/group/python-excel/browse_thread/thread/5c07232e17c20af0/d8a4900e7f67e20f?lnk=gst&q=autofilter#d8a4900e7f67e20f) in a Google group. It looks like it's not possible, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue, running a linux server.

i'm going to check creating an ODS or XLSX file with auto-filter by other means, and then convert them with a libreoffice command line to "xls".

Comment: You can add autofilters with XlsxWriter. See this [example](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/example_autofilter.html#ex-autofilter).

Comment: @jmcnamara  SORRY   This page does not exist yet.